# Check JComboBox Value

Tags: java, database, swing, jcombobox, jlist

I need to create a new method to check the value of the selected item in combo box.
That combo box is populated from database.

This is how get the selected item:

```
 combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String x=(String) combo.getSelectedItem();
```

The string "x" save the value of selected item because I need to use "x" in my other query.

```
    ResultSet st = stt.executeQuery("Select Name from Table where Number="+x+"");
```

With that query I can populate the `JList`.

The problem is, when I select another item in combo box, the list does not update.
So I need to create another statement to check the combo box value? If yes, how?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: sry :p im new here ^^

Comment: There is no need for apologies.  But please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please' (even in comments).  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.  And before you apologize again, I would prefer to hear "Will try to take care of that in future" rather than "Sorry", since the 1st one is a lot more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your `JList` use a `ListModel` that also implements `ActionListener`. Add this specialized  listener to the combo. Each time the combo changes, your `ListModel`'s action listener will be invoked. In the listener, you can update the `ListModel` in place.

Addendum: Here's the basic approach.

[image]

```
/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16587357/230513
 */
public class ListListenerTest {

    private static final String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(items);
    private JList list = new JList(new MyModel(combo));

    private static class MyModel extends DefaultListModel implements ActionListener {

        private JComboBox combo;

        public MyModel(JComboBox combo) {
            this.combo = combo;
            addElement(combo.getSelectedItem());
            combo.addActionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            set(0, combo.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println("Combo changed.");
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ListListenerTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        f.add(combo);
        f.add(list);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ListListenerTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```